# In Tensorflow how do I make a dataset with objects & corresponding labels from an image

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a symbol key, I'm looking for advice regarding a way to **extract these symbols with their text as labels for a dataset**; to then later be used to match these symbols on their engineering diagrams.

I'm just looking for a push in the right direction, I have experience with Tensorflow; just note quite sure how to go about tackling this one.

**Simple Example**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RBau.png

**Complex Example**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRLWf.png

Looking for a push in the right direction, thanks for the help guys!

I haven't tried much as I'm confused what to even try in the first place, I haven't worked with documents like this before.